# Let $A\in M_3(\mathbb{R})$ be a non-null matrix such as $A^3=-A$. Show that $A$ is similar to the matrix $P$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, minimal-polynomials, similar-matrices

> Let $A\in M_3(\mathbb{R})$ be a non-null matrix such as $A^3=-A$. Show that $A$ is similar to the matrix $$P = \begin{bmatrix}
> 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & -1 \\
> 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{bmatrix}$$.

Hey, I hope you are doing well. I'm trying to do this:

If $A^3=-A$, then $A^3+A=0$, so the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p_A(x)=x^3+x=x(x^2+1)$,

from this we can conclude that the minimal polynomial is $m_A(x)=x(x^2+1)=x^3+x$.

We also have that the companion matrix for $m_A$ is $$B=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$.

Then, Can I only show that $B$ is similar to $P$ and I am done?

Comment: Every eigenvalue of $A$ is a root of the minimal polynomial, so you know $m_A(x)$ is divisible by $x$. So it cannot be $x^2+1$. You know there is an eigenvector corresponding to $0$, and you should find a $2$-dimensional invariant subspace. corresponding to the factor $x^2+1$.

Comment: There is a bit of work to go from "$A^3+A=0$" to "the characteristic polynomial is $x(x^2+1)$". You should show that work.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Is there a way to see $p_A(x)=x^3+x$ that doesn't first show $m_A(x)=x^3+x$ to find $p_A$ by Cauchy-Hamilton?  The way I see it, we have $m_A(x) \mid x^3+x$, so either $m_A(x)=x$ (but then $A=0$) or $m_A(x)=x^2+1$ (but then $\deg(p_A)=3$ is even) or $m_A(x)=x^3+x$.  I can't see any other route to the characteristic polynomial, but this makes all the work in the question/comments/answer I see here feel backwards.

Comment: @BrianMoehring: Because $A^3+A=0$, we know the minimal polynomial divides $x^3+x$, so the factors of the characteristic polynomial are among $x$ and $x^2+1$. It cannot just be $x$, because then we have that the characteristic polynomial is $x^3$ and the minimal is $x$, so $A=0$. It cannot just have $x^2+1$ as a factor, because then you can't get a polynomial of degree $3$. So the only possibility is that the characteristic polynomial is exactly $x(x^2+1)$.  Same argument can be used to deduce $m_A(x)=x^3+x$ directly, without the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @BrianMoehring In any case, jumping to "Aha, the characteristic polynomial must be $x^3+x$" is essentially assuming that you already know the minimal polynomial is $x^3+x$, which does indeed beg the question.  P.S. Cayley-Hamilton

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oops... with how much Cauchy did, I'm not surprised I made that error, but a lil' embarrassing all the same.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm no sure if the following is correct (someone can correct me): Since the minimal polynomial of $P$ is also $x^3+x$ we can say they have the same rational form, then they are similar, here the invariant factors are the same because they have the same dimension (3).

Answer (score 2):

The roots of the characteristic polynomial are always roots of the minimal polynomial. Therefore, the minimal polynomial is $x^3+x$.

Since $0$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial with multiplicity $1$, $\dim\ker A=1$. Take $v\in\ker A$ and let $R$ be the range of $A$. By the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim R=2$. For each $w\in R$, $w=A.v$ for some $v\in\Bbb R^3$, and therefore\begin{align}(A^2+\operatorname{Id}).w&=(A^2+\operatorname{Id}).(A.v)\\&=(A^3+A).v\\&=0.\end{align}Take $w_1\in R\setminus\{0\}$ and let $w_2=A.w_1$. Then$$A.w_2=A^2.w_1=-w_1.$$It is not hard to prove that $\{v,w_1,w_2\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^3$ and, since $A.v=0$, $A.w_1=w_2$, and $A.w_2=-w_1$, $A$ is indeed similar to$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$